# Not redirect to the same component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My component not redirect to same component with different parameters.

```
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.REACT_APP_DEFAULT_PATH ?? ''}>
        <Switch>
            ...
            <Route exact path={"/admin/logs/:page"} component={Logs} key={"Logs"} />
            ...
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

And in component:

```
    this.props.history.push("/admin/logs/" + page);
```

It change the url in browser, but not redirect

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code? I would like to take a look at it

Comment: You should use the router hook that is provided by the react router API for history pushes... It's not clear in your code where `this.props.history` comes from

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to put strings for component, it needs to be an actual component. `<Route exact path={"/admin/logs/:page"} component={Logs} key={"Logs"} />`

Comment: @lanxion I wrote incorrect example. I use actual component as parameter. Question has been marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your component is already matched and mounted/rendered it now needs to also "listen" for changes to the route props that are passed to it.

I see that you are using a class-based component from `this.props.history.push("/admin/logs/" + page);` so you need to implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.match.params.page !== prevProps.match.params.page) {
    // page updated, do something
  }
}
```